# Have trouble identifying and deleting a line - should be simple

Tags: regex, bash, sed

So this should be easy, but I just can't seem to get it right. I have the following data:

```
 4131942         Door Assy, LH Ref 249R/RP
 15              #7002668 - Rev. A - June, 2006
 1.             6110010 Bolt, #10-24 x 1/2” Flat Head
```

and I want to delete the middle line.

This is the most recent iteration of the statement that I am using:

```
 sed -i '/(^[(0-9)][(0-9)](.*)[#][(0-9)][(0-9)][(0-9)][(0-9)][(0-9)][(0-9)][(0-9)](.*))/d'
```

I have used multiple variation and different regexps, to no avail.

What am I missing here?

Comment: What is the criteria you have to delete middle line? 2 digit then # then 7 digits?

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is ok, but you need to use `sed -r` in order to enable extended regular expressions.

Try:

```
sed -ri '/(^[(0-9)][(0-9)](.*)[#][(0-9)][(0-9)][(0-9)][(0-9)][(0-9)][(0-9)][(0-9)](.*))/d'  file
```

Alternatively, simplify it to:

```
sed -ri  '/^[0-9]{2}.*#[0-9]{7}.*/d' file
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you very much. I was probably over thinking it.

Comment: @DominicRomano if this answer solved your question, please consider marking it as "accepted".